# how do I remove positive potion effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was on a server and the people had a game to drink a potion and it was either good or bad. Mine turned out to be good - but not in my opinion. It had speed on it and I couldn't go anywhere without traveling 1 million miles away. I tried drinking milk and it wouldn't work. It's so annoying. What do I do??!!

Comment: You could try holding shift to cut the speed down to 2/3 and if you block with a sword that'll bring it down another 1/3, so if you do both you'll be going a third of you speedy self.  But that is too tedious, You might be able to contact a Server Administrator to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Potions have a time duration on it normally so just wait until the time for the potion effect runs out.

You could race your friends, which means you would always win due to the speed boost. But while you are waiting, practice using the potion correctly since it could help you run away from an evil group of mobs who wanna kill you. And have fun with it too!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in creative mode, or a server administrator or administratrix is online, try running the command `/effect @p clear`.